# How to run Tidy-html5 (aka HTML Tidy) recursively on all html files?

Tags: tidy, htmltidy

I would like to run [HTML Tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/) (aka tidy-html5) recursively on all the html files including those in the sub-directories.   While `tidy -mq ./src/*.html` works on all html files in the src directory, it does not run on sub-directories.

My HTML directory structure looks like this, and each directory contains multiple html files:

```
└── src/
    ├── 2017-12-01-post1/*.html
    ├── 2017-12-15-post2/*.html
    ├── 2018-01-03-post3/*.html
    ├── 2018-04-01-post4/*.html
    └── ... (more dir)
```

Is it possible to do something like `tidy -mq ./src/**/*.html`?  (Similar to how Prettier works)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I settled on using `find` command (Linux, Mac, *nix, BSD) like this :

```
find . -name '*.html' -type f -print -exec tidy -mq '{}' \;
```

This will search through the directories recursively for all HTML files and execute `tidy` on them.

Alternatively, in Bash, use `shopt -s globstar`:

```
shopt -s globstar
tidy -mq **/*.html
```

In ZSH, it just works without any other setting:

```
tidy -mq **/*.html
```